# How do you parse with SAX using Attributes & Values to a URL path using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, attributes, saxparser

I'm trying to get my head around parsing with SAX and thought a good place to start was the TopSongs example found at the iPhone Dev Center. I get most of it but when it comes to reaching Attributes and Values within a node I can't find a good example anywhere. The XML has a path to a URL for the coverArt. And the XML node looks like this.

```
<itms:coverArt height="60" width="60">http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/026/Music/aa/aa/27/mzi.pbxnbfvw.60x60-50.jpg</itms:coverArt>
```

What I've tried is this for the startElement…

```
 ((prefix != NULL && !strncmp((const char *)prefix, kName_Itms, kLength_Itms)) && 
        (!strncmp((const char *)localname, kName_CoverArt, kLength_Item) &&
         !strncmp((const char *)attributes, kAttributeName_CoverArt, kAttributeLength_CoverArt) &&
         !strncmp((const char *)attributes, kValueName_CoverArt, kValueLength_CoverArt) ||
         !strncmp((const char *)localname, kName_Artist, kLength_Artist) ||
```

and picking it up again with just the localname at the end like this.

```
if (!strncmp((const char *)localname, kName_CoverArt, kLength_CoverArt)) { importer.currentSong.coverArt = [NSURL URLWithString:importer.currentString];
```

The trace is -[Song setCoverArt:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't synthesized the `coverArt` property in your `Song` class (using the `@synthesize` keyword). That's what creates the `-[Song setCoverArt:]` method which is called when you set the `coverArt` property on `currentSong`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, It follows the same structure as the other nodes which are set to be @dynamic in the Song class. But I think you're right it's not getting added to the data model correctly. I've since tried adding just another node without attributes and it produced the same error result.

Comment: I hadn't added the new attribute to the Data Model file which is what threw the error. Now I have I don't get the error but I also don't get the data. So there must be something missing from the structure above.

Comment: I can reach the data as a string with a single call on the node but the problem is there are three nodes for different picture sizes. So I'm gong to still need to know how to reach the others.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting closer. I need to do a for loop to collect the right attributes. The problem now is dealing with the endelementSAX. It is still picking up all three entries even though 2 have no data.